# Selecting unique records from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, union

**The setting**

I have a database with two tables. One of which is for inbox messages (`inbox`) and the other one is for outbox messages (`outbox`). They both have identical structure and some records.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| inbox                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| messageID | from  | to    | messageText | timestamp        |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1         | userA | userB | sometext    | 2013-06-19 10:30 |
| 2         | userB | userC | sometext    | 2013-06-19 10:40 |
| 3         | userC | userA | sometext    | 2013-06-19 10:50 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| outbox                                                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| messageID | from  | to    | messageText | timestamp        |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1         | userA | userC | sometext    | 2013-06-19 10:20 |
| 2         | userC | userB | sometext    | 2013-06-19 10:30 |
| 3         | userB | userA | sometext    | 2013-06-19 10:35 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**The problem**

I need to select every last message from every conversation of a particular user (in this case - I want to retrieve every last message from the conversations of the userA) in whichever table the message is - inbox or outbox. I have managed to select the last message for each conversation from inbox and outbox with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT from, to, timestamp, messageText, messageID
    FROM inbox
    WHERE to = 'userA'
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
)
AS tmp_table GROUP BY from
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT from, to, timestamp, messageText, messageID
    FROM outbox 
    WHERE from = 'userA'
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
)
AS tmp_table GROUP BY to
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

So now I need to check which message is newer - the one in the inbox or the one outbox (if messages exist in both tables between the two users, of course) and only return the latest messages.

Or maybe my approach is downright silly - please comment : D Thanks.

Comment: Honestly there's no reason to store that data in two separate tables.

Comment: i agree with @Jessica, one table and worries over. try adding `limit 1'

Comment: @Jessica - yes, I now - I would definitely use different structure, but sadly I'm stuck with this one since I am not allowed to modify it by the "client".

Comment: @amigura how would a "limit 1" help me? It would return a single row form the table. That is not my goal.

Comment: You said that your goal is to retrieve the latest message for userA - that *would* be only a single row from the tables. Do you want the latest row for *each* user?

Comment: btw is messageid auto or is it an actual id for messages meaning that messageid would be 1,1,2,3 inbox and 1,1,2,3 outbox.

Comment: @MarkBannister I'm sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. The userA has sent to and retrieved messages from different users - userB, userC, userD. It means that there are different conversations: 1) userA with userB 2) userA with userC etc. And I want to retrieve the last message in each of these conversations. I edited the question, maybe it will be more clear that way.

Comment: you could just use php to determine which of the two messages are new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what indexes are set up on your tables it may be possible to write a faster-performing query, but this should work:

```
select 
    sq.main_user, 
    sq.other_user, 
    coalesce(i.messageText, o.messageText) messageText
from 
   (select 
        main_user, other_user, max(msg_time) last_msg 
    from
        (select 
             `from` main_user, `to` other_user, `timestamp` msg_time 
         from outbox
         where `from` = 'userA'
         union all
         select 
             `to` main_user, `from` other_user, `timestamp` msg_time 
         from inbox
         where `to` = 'userA') uq
      group by main_user, other_user) sq
left join 
    outbox o on sq.main_user = o.`from` and sq.last_msg = o.`timestamp`
left join 
    inbox i on sq.main_user = i.`to` and sq.last_msg = i.`timestamp`
```

(Omit the `where` clauses from the innermost subquery if you want to see conversations for all users, not just userA.)

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Sadly I would have never written something like this myself. If you could also explain what is going on here, because I have no clue how it works :D

Comment: @August: The innermost query (aliased as `uq`) selects all message `timestamp`s from or to 'userA', with 'userA' as `main_user` and the other user as (surprisingly) `other_user`. The intermediate subquery (aliased as `sq`) summarises the result from `uq` to get the largest (ie. most recent) `timestamp` for each combination of `main_user` and `other_user`. Then the main query optionally joins to the inbox and outbox tables from `sq` on the `main_user` and most recent `timestamp` - for each combination of `main_user` and `other_user`, only one of the two tables should have a matching record.

Comment: @August: The `coalesce` ensures that `messageText` is selected from whichever table's record is populated for the most recent message.

Answer (score 2):

Just get the top 1 record from each table, then union the results:

```
SELECT 'outbox', *
FROM outbox
WHERE `from` = 'userA'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'inbox', *
FROM inbox
WHERE `from` = 'userA'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Notes:

1) note the backticks around `from`. `FROM` is a reserved word in pretty much EVERY sql database under the sun, so your query would never work without barfing with a syntax error
2) note the hardcoded `'inbox'` and `'outbox'` strings in the two subqueries - they're there to tell you WHICH table the found records came from.

Comment: Are you sure that will work? It now seems that the query would select a single row from every table. And there might be thousands of rows  that I need (userA can have conversations with thousands of users).

Comment: it'll grab all the messages where userA is the `from` person, but only return the most recent one, because it's sorting dates descending, and returning only the first row (limit 1). so this query would only ever return two rows at most. one from inbox, and one from outbox.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that my question was not clear. I want to retrieve the most recent messages for all conversations that the userA had - i. e. if there is a record in the inbox where to=userA and from=userB with a timestamp of 2013-06-01 AND a record in outbox  where from=userA and to=userB with a timestamp of 2013-06-19 then the query should return the latter record. And if there are more conversations (userA with userC) - then the query should also return the last message in this conversation too.